# Compare values in two files

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have two files Which should contain the same values between Substring 0 and 10 though not in order. I have Managed to Outprint the values in each file but I need to Know how to Report say id the Value is in the first File and Notin the second file and vice versa. The files are in these formats.

```
6436346346....Other details
9348734873....Other details
9349839829....Other details
```

second file

```
8484545487....Other details
9348734873....Other details
9349839829....Other details
```

The first record in the first file does not appear in the second file and the first record in the second file does not appear in the first file. I need to be able to report this mismatch in this format:

```
Record 6436346346 is in the firstfile and not in the secondfile.
Record 8484545487 is in the secondfile and not in the firstfile.
```

Here is the code I currently have that gives me the required Output from the two files to compare.

```
package compare.numbers;

import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author implvcb
 */
 public class CompareNumbers {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File f = new File("C:/Analysis/");
    String line;
    String line1;
    try {
        String firstfile = "C:/Analysis/RL001.TXT";
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(firstfile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String account = line.substring(0, 10);
             System.out.println(account);


        }
        String secondfile = "C:/Analysis/RL003.TXT";
        FileInputStream fs1 = new FileInputStream(secondfile);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs1));
        while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            String account1 = line1.substring(0, 10);
            System.out.println(account1);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

Please help on how I can effectively achieve this.
I think I needed to say that am new to java and may not grab the ideas that easily but Am trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code to do that:

```
 public static void eliminateCommon(String file1, String file2) throws IOException
{
    List<String> lines1 = readLines(file1);
    List<String> lines2 = readLines(file2);

    Iterator<String> linesItr = lines1.iterator();
    while (linesItr.hasNext()) {
        String checkLine = linesItr.next();
        if (lines2.contains(checkLine)) {
            linesItr.remove();
            lines2.remove(checkLine);
        }
    }

    //now lines1 will contain string that are not present in lines2
    //now lines2 will contain string that are not present in lines1
    System.out.println(lines1);
    System.out.println(lines2);

}

public static List<String> readLines(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String account = line.substring(0, 10);
        lines.add(account);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Using sets would be more efficient for searches.

Comment: @Stanley At the end of eliminateCommon() you have comments. Both the lists contain unique id's. You can print in your own fashion.

Comment: `System.out.println(lines1)` and `System.out.println(lines2)` does not outprint anything Either.

Comment: Thank you Ramesh I think This is what I have been looking for, One last thing, The Output is in an Arrayin the form: [2632323236, 734343476, 34734343834],c an I get the Numbers each On its own Line?

Comment: lines1 does return the records not in lines2 but linees2 returns even the records in the First file

Comment: Could be whitespace issues. Try trimming the values before adding to the list. I did not get what do you mean by this "c an I get the Numbers each On its own Line? "

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(FileUtils.readLines(new File("C:/Analysis/RL001.TXT")));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(FileUtils.readLines(new File("C:/Analysis/RL003.TXT")));

Set<String> onlyInSet1 = new HashSet<>(set1);
onlyInSet1.removeAll(set2);

Set<String> onlyInSet2 = new HashSet<>(set2);
onlyInSet2.removeAll(set1);
```

Comment: So what parameter represents what is in file 1 and not in file and what is in FIle 2 and not in file1?

Comment: Got an Error: Diamond separator not supported in source 1.6

Comment: `onlyInSet1` = "what is in file 1 and not in file" 2

Comment: You can fill in the `<String>` type. ;)

Comment: `FileUtils` is from http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: What is to Fill in the Styring type?

Comment: find and replace `<>` with `<String>`

Comment: Thank Peter, two issues though, one, The output comes in One line, Can I have it in Different lines? Two, I am not ineterested in the Whole Line, I am Only Interested in the `Substring(0, 10)` of every line in the two files. How DO I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you guarantee that the files will always be the same format, and each readLine() function is going to return a different number, why not have an array of strings, rather than a single string. You can then compare the outcome with greater ease.

Answer (score 1):

- Put values from each file to two separate `HashSet`s accordingly.
- Iterate over one of the `HashSet`s and check whether each value exists in the other `HashSet`. Report if not.
- Iterate over other `HashSet` and do same thing for this.

Comment: Even easier: `hashset1.removeAll(hashset2)`. All elements that remain, are singular. Then do the same thing in the other direction (of course with new sets).

Answer (score 1):

Open two Scanners, and :

```
    final TreeSet<Integer> ts1 = new TreeSet<Integer>();    
    final TreeSet<Integer> ts2 = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    while (scan1.hasNextLine() && scan2.hasNexLine) {
            ts1.add(Integer.valueOf(scan1.nextLigne().subString(0,10));
            ts1.add(Integer.valueOf(scan1.nextLigne().subString(0,10));
        }
You can now compare ordered results of the two trees
```

**EDIT**
Modified with TreeSet

Comment: Are numbers given in sorted order (increasing or decreasing)? If this is not guaranteed, this solution will not work. (Example in the question not sorted)

Comment: Nope the Numbers are in a random way there is no order of outprinting the Numbers.

Comment: OP said that values are not in order.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first I would save the two sets of strings in to collections

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(), s2 = new HashSet<String>();
//...
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  //...
  s1.add(line);
}
```

Then you can compare those sets and find elements that do not appear in both sets. You can find some ideas on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341202/fastest-way-to-compare-two-set-in-java).

If you need to know the line number as well, you could just create a String wrapper:

```
class Element {
  public String str;
  public int lineNr;

  public boolean equals(Element compElement) {
    return compElement.str.equals(str);
  }
}
```

Then you can just use `Set<Element>` instead.