# How to test if a generic list contains the exact subcollection of a subtype in Java?

Tags: java, generics, collections, junit, bounded-wildcard

I have an abstract class, AbstractService, and several classes which extend this abstract class:

[image: Silly class diagram]

I then have a ServiceFactory that returns me a generic list with some services, according to a parameter I pass:

```
public class ServiceFactory {
    public List<? extends AbstractService> getServices(final MyParameter param) {
        // Service is an interface implemented by AbstractService
        List<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Foo foo : param.getFoos()) {
            services.add(new AService(foo.getBar()));
        }
        // creates the rest of the services
        return services;
    }
}
```

In my UnitTest, I'd like to verify if my list of services contains exactly 3 AService subtypes. The way I'm doing that now is:

```
@Test
public void serviceFactoryShouldReturnAServiceForEachFoo() {
  // I'm mocking MyParameter and Foo here
  Mockito.when(param.getFoos()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(foo, foo, foo);

  AService aservice = new AService(foo);

  List<AService> expectedServices = Arrays.asList(aservice, aservice, aservice);
  List<? extends AbstractService> actualServices = serviceFactory.getServices();

  assertTrue(CollectionUtils.isSubCollection(expectedServices, actualServices));
}
```

When actualServices contains less than 3 Aservice, the test fails correctly. The only problem with this solution is that if actualServices contains more than 3 AService, the test passes...

Is there a method that does that or should I implement it myself using loops?

Comment: I would use Set and probably checkout the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341202/fastest-way-to-compare-two-set-in-java

Comment: Is your example code right? You put 3 of the same thing into your `expectedServices` list. Are you looking to count the number of different classes in your list, to see if that number is 3?

Comment: @DanGetz not exactly. In my app, I add these services to the list according to another parameter, so the services are not all the same, and they do not always return exactly 3. But in my unit test, I am using mock parameters to get that expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use hamcrest Matchers.

[hamcrest-library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library) contains matchers to check collection/iterable contents.

I hope the following sample matches your szenario loosely

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ServiceFactoryTest
{
    @Test
    public void serviceFactoryShouldReturnAServiceForEachFoo()
    {
        Foo foo = mock( Foo.class );
        Service service = new AService( foo );
        Service[] expected = { service, service, service };
        Service[] tooFew = { service, service };
        Service[] tooMany = { service, service, service, service };

        ServiceFactory factory = new ServiceFactory();

        assertThat( factory.createServices( foo, foo, foo ), containsInAnyOrder( expected ) );
        assertThat( factory.createServices( foo, foo, foo ), not( containsInAnyOrder( tooFew ) ) );
        assertThat( factory.createServices( foo, foo, foo ), not( containsInAnyOrder( tooMany ) ) );
    }

    interface Foo
    {}

    interface Service
    {}

    class AService implements Service
    {
        Foo foo;

        public AService( Foo foo )
        {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals( Object that )
        {
            return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals( this, that );
        }
    }

    class ServiceFactory
    {
        Collection<? extends Service> createServices( Foo... foos )
        {
            Collection<Service> list = new ArrayList<>();

            for ( Foo foo : foos )
            {
                list.add( new AService( foo ) );
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but the test fails when there are more types of services in the list (AnotherService, for instance). Nonetheless, I should use really learn these matchers.

Comment: In this case you should probably just assert the size in this test and test the proper service creation in its own test - like createFooServiceForFoo() and createBarServiceForBar().
the contains/containsInAnyOrder Matcher also accepts a collection of matchers, so you could use instanceOf(Class) Matchers instead of equals checks.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely the case that subtypes of AService are instances of AService and the condition returning true is correct.

There isn't even a good way to implement it using loops and a lot depends on the execution context, "same" classes loaded from different class loaders are "different".

I would take a step back and think about the property of AService that you wish to verify, should that property be defined in AbstractService? And, finally use the property to verify the results.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But I'm not testing my AService class, but a Factory that returns a list of services. I'm going to improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to Max Fichtelmann to point me in the right direction!

I ultimately started using [Fest assert](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x), but the same result can probably be achieved with Hamcrest.

I created a custom matcher, `assertEvery`, comparing list sizes:

```
public class ServiceAssert extends AbstractAssert<ServiceAssert, List<Service>> {
  public ServiceAssert(List<Service> actual) {
    super(actual, ServiceAssert.class);
  }

  // it's usually assertThat, but it conflicts with the List<T> assertions
  public static ServiceAssert assertThatMy(List<Service> actual) {
    return new ServiceAssert(actual);
  }

  public ServiceAssert containsEvery(List<? extends Service> expectedServices) {
    Integer listSize = 0;

    isNotNull();

    if (expectedServices == null || expectedServices.isEmpty()) {
      throw new AssertionError("Do not use this method for an empty or null list of services, use doesNotContain instead.");
    }

    Class<? extends Service> serviceClass = expectedServices.get(0).getClass();

    for (Service f : actual) {
      if (f.getClass().equals(serviceClass)) {
        listSize++;
      }
    }

    if (listSize != expectedServices.size()) {
      throw new AssertionError("expected " + expectedServices.size() + " " + serviceClass.getSimpleName() + " but was " + listSize + ".");
    }

    return this;
  }
}
```

Now, I can use it with `import static myassertions.impl.ServiceAssert.assertThatMy;`.