# When will equal and hashcode methods of AbstractSet get called?

Tags: java, collections

When will equal() and hashcode() methods of AbstractSet get called?
What is the need of those methods in AbstractSet?

Comment: Because that is why they exist. Being called is the sole purpose of a method.

Comment: When they need to be called.

Comment: you'll have to be a bit more specific, if you want an answer.

Comment: I guess we can't answer your question; because it doesn't seem to make sense. Maybe you should explain **why** you think you need to know that ... that could help us to resolve your "real" problem.

Comment: what is the  need of those methods in AbstractSet?

Comment: since we use both equals and hashcode methods in hashing algorithms , wrapper classes already consisting of these methods. What is the need of defining those methods in AbstractSet? Does any of the collection class uses these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractSet's equals and hashcode methods will get inherited by any subclass of AbstractSet that doesn't override them. They would get called when using that set as an element in a collection or map.

The methods use the contained elements to determine whether this set is equal to another. The JDK subclasses [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), and [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) use these implementations of equals and hashCode, the API documentation lists them under **Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractSet**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341202/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-sets-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question for hashcode() by trying the sample example.
hashcode() method will get called when you add set elements in hashmap as key
eg:

Set<`String`> set = new HashSet<`String`>();
set.add("A");
set.add("B");
Map<`Set<`String`>,String`> m = new HashMap<`Set<`String`>,String`>();
m.put(set,"B");

put debug point in hashcode() method of AbstractSet it will get called.