# Java - Best way to compare two Sets by hashes (via ==)

Tags: java, set

I have two Sets of Strings. Strings are the same (`==` returns `true`). I believe that comparing via `==` should be faster than comparing via `equals()` or `hashCode()`. So how to make sure they are the same not using `equals()`? Thanks

Comment: Why would you *not* want to use `equals`? Maybe comparing by identity is a bit faster, but is the extra speed actually meaningful?

Comment: I'm a previous C++ user. I through that comparing using == is something like comaping addresses of JVM objects and should be faster than comapring by identity. Isn't so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to compare two sets in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341202/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-sets-in-java)

Comment: @Ivan It's faster, but it'll give you back a meaningless answer, so what's the point?  It'd be faster to do nothing, but it's not like that'd help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the two `Set`s are not the same instance, you can't use `==` to compare the `Set`s.

Now, if you use `Set`'s `equals`, it (and by "it" I mean the default implementation of `AbstractSet`) will validate the two `Set`s have the same size and then iterate over the elements of one `Set` and check if the other `Set` contains each of them.

If, for example, you are using `HashSet`s, in order to find if a `String` is contained in some `HashSet`, `hashCode()` will have to be used to find the bucket that may contain the searched `String`, but later `String`'s `equals()` will be called to validate the presence of a `String` equal to the searched `String`. `String`'s `equals()` actually begins with

```
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
```

so the fact that your two `Set`s may contain references to the same `String` instance will be helpful in improving the runtime of the `Set`s comparison.