# Compare two hashmaps in java for equal key values

Tags: java

I have two maps:

```
Map1.put(a,1)
Map1.put(b,2)
Map1.put(c,3)
Map1.put(d,4)

Map2.put(a,1)
Map2.put(b,5)
Map2.put(c,3)
Map2.put(d,4)
Map2.put(e,6)
Map2.put(f,9)
```

How do I compare Map1 and Map2 for equal key values? If the key is not matching in Map2 then ignore that key.

Comment: Extract the key sets from each map and use the methods outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3341202/13075.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to compare two sets in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341202/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-sets-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

get the `keySet()` of every map and  use the `ContainsAll()` method

```java
Map<String, Integer> Map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map1.put("a", 1);
Map1.put("b", 2);
Map1.put("c", 3);
Map1.put("d", 4);

Map<String, Integer> Map2 = new HashMap<>();
Map2.put("a", 1);
Map2.put("b", 5);
Map2.put("c", 3);
Map2.put("d", 4);
Map2.put("e", 6);
Map2.put("f", 9);

// check if all keys from Map1 are present in Map2
System.out.println(Map2.keySet().containsAll(Map1.keySet()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `intersection()` with Entries. It will check keys and values and return common entries.

```java
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("a", 1);
map1.put("b", 2);
map1.put("c", 3);
map1.put("d", 4);

Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("a", 2);
map2.put("b", 3);
map2.put("c", 4);
map2.put("d", 5);
map2.put("e", 6);
map2.put("f", 9);

Collection<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> commonValues = CollectionUtils.intersection(map1.entrySet(), map2.entrySet());

System.out.println(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(commonValues)); // if empty, then no same key and value found.
```

For keys alone use :

```java
Collection<String> commonKeys = CollectionUtils.intersection(map1.keySet(), map2.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another simple solution.

```
Map1.keySet().retainAll(Map2.keySet());
```

Map1.keySet() contains only keys in both sets