# How can I compare two hashmaps to see if the keys are equal?

Tags: java

I have two hashmaps let's say `hashmap1` and `hashmap2` so that `hashmap2` contains common keys with `hashmap1`. So, I want to check that if the keys are common or equal in both hashmaps, then I multiply the values of `hashmap2` by 2 in each iteration.

My code is as follows but it gives me zero. Actually, I want to practice the operation otherwise I can easily multiply the values of `hashmap2` without comparing with `hashmap1`.

```
double mult=2;
        for(String s:hashmap1.keySet()) {


            if(hashmap1.keySet()==hashmap2.keySet()) {

                mult= mult * hashmap1.get(s);
            }else {
                continue;
                }

            }

        System.out.println("The new values for hashmap2: " + mult);
```

Moreover, the keys for hashmaps are `String`

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: I don't think you can compare the return of keyset() with ==, it will just check if that's the same object (which won't be the case)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to compare two sets in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341202/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-sets-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below code resolve your issue

```
Map<String, Integer> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap1.put("A", 2);
    hashMap1.put("B", 3);

    Map<String, Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap2.put("A", 2);
    hashMap2.put("B", 3);
    hashMap2.put("C", 4);

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entryHashMap2 : hashMap2.entrySet()) {
        if (hashMap1.containsKey(entryHashMap2.getKey())) {
        System.out.println(entryHashMap2.getValue() * 2);
        hashMap2.put(entryHashMap2.getKey(), (entryHashMap2.getValue() * 2));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you initialize `mult` with zero, so every time you multiply by zero, you get zero.

Regarding your question, you should do `hashmap1.keySet().equals(hashmap2.keySet())` to check if two sets are equal.

Comment: Yes sure, I changed it to 2 but again it gives me zero. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for this

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            map1.put("a", 1);
            map1.put("b", 2);
            Map map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            map2.put("a", 1);
            map2.put("b", 3);
            map2.put("c", 3);
            System.out.println(map1.keySet().equals(map2.keySet()));
            if (map1.keySet().equals(map2.keySet())) {
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = map2.entrySet().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
                    map2.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() * 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```